# CKEditor automatically making new paragraphs

Tags: wysiwyg

When I'm writing some text with CKeditor and I press enter and want to write something on the next line, the editor automatically inserts the text on the new line into `<p> ... </p>` tags instead of only `<br/>`
.

I tried to correct it with editing the `config.js` file and adding the line `config.autoParagraph = false;` but without success.

Do you know where is the fault?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Out of the box, the CKEditor configuration does a `<p>` on enter and a `<br>` on shift + enter.

If you wish to change this, you can visit admin/settings/ckeditor/edit/[profile], and scroll down to the "Cleanup and output" section.

Answer (score 5):

Answer above fix this if you have a [CKEditor](http://drupal.org/project/ckeditor) module, but if you use [WYSIWYG](http://drupal.org/project/wysiwyg) module you don't have that option (at least for now).

Here is how to override these settings with a module in CKEeditor in Drupal 7:

```
function YOURMODULENAME_wysiwyg_editor_settings_alter(&$settings, $context) {
  if($context['profile']->editor == 'ckeditor') {
    $settings['enterMode'] = 2; //<br />
    $settings['shiftEnterMode'] = 1; //<p>
  }
}
```

For TinyMCE here [Drupal 7 - How to change p to br in CKEditor and TinyMCE](http://www.wdtutorials.com/drupal7/50).

Answer (score 2):

There is a reason why the paragraph is the default: usually it's semantically more correct to use a `<p>` tag. I recommend in most cases to stick to the default and (if you don't like the whitespace) remove the margin on paragraphs using CSS.

Answer (score 2):

Just go to admin/settings/filters/list; uncheck "Line break" in all filters, and "Full HTML."

Answer (score 1):

I found it easier to hardcode this.
Open the file sites/all/libraries/ckeditor/ckeditor.js in Notepad++
Go to line 22 or search for shiftEnterMode

Change following:

```
enterMode:1,forceEnterMode:false,shiftEnterMode:2,
```

into:

```
enterMode:2,forceEnterMode:false,shiftEnterMode:1,
```

done!